# How do I prevent replay attacks/reuse of receipts when users restore in app purchases on iOS?

Tags: ios, security, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

If a user makes a purchase, in order to prevent replay attacks (the user reusing an old receipt to get new content) I check if that transaction identifier has been used before. If so, rejected. It works great.

However, when the user "restores previous purchases", how do I prevent it here? It's expected that the transaction has been seen before as it was previously purchased, but how do I know that the receipt is from that specific user and not a replay attack from a common receipt?

Can I link it to a specific user? It seems silly to prevent replay attacks on purchase when they could just tap restore to get around it...

Comment: On some application that I work in we prevent this using our server, we keep the receipt and check if is a purchase, restore or an attack

Comment: @ReinierMelian But how do you do that? (Deem it's a valid restore?)

Comment: Our server validates our purchases ir order to avoid this problems, I send the receipt and our server check if is valid and then we react properly, I know this are not detailed answer but, is what I can remember